# no "hello world " output (c++)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

If I run the code::blocks default console c++ "hello world" app (see below), I only see this in the console that opens :

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.011 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I don't see "hello world". What could be wrong ?

If I run the ./helloworld.exe with cygwin, I do see "hello world".   But I don't see it with cmd or powershell.

The app :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `./keylogger.exe` <-- this is weird name for hello-world app. Other than that, cygwin probably emulates Unix-like ttys for output, and cmd/PowerShell likely use Win32 APIs for console which are completely different beasts (but they supported by MSVCRT).

Comment: It doesn't explain why it's not outputting "hello world" when running the app in code::blocks. The name of the app doesn't matter.

Comment: You might be unwittingly unlinking with "-mwindows" at the command line, beyond that without any other information, you might be using a dodgy compiler, i'd say try installing min gw yourself. If you still have no look then you could just grab vs 2017 community, you can now use clang as well as msvc++ :-).

Comment: It works!!  "mwindows" was the culprit. Thanks @George   .  But look :  I needed to deselect the "mwindows" flag ,restart code::blocks, rebuild the project.  Now I see "hello world".  Then I could reselect the "mwindows" flag, and restarting/rebuild.  Now it works with "mwindows" too.

Comment: Hmmm, you could try deleting the build folder after running your project with the flag on, and then re building (I imagine your program wouldn't write anything to the console but i'm not 100%). If I were you, unless you really want to use min gw, I would just get vs 2017 for support and stability (as well as a pretty shit hot debugger and some other nice features) :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @George.

Solution was to remove the -mwindows compiler flag.

But to make it work, I needed to delete the .exe before building again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related discussion you might want to check out here:

http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/244674-49-basic-program

It could be a matter of the program executing too quickly, per the forum I referenced above, but that seems like an odd reason. You might try what they recommend (pause, etc.), but you may also have an issue with your compiler or how your properties are set up.

For cmd, check this out:

https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/09/how-to-run-c-and-cpp-program-in-cmd.html

For the command line/Windows prompt, check this out:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

Comment: First link solution not working. No "hello world" output with `cin.get()` or `system("pause")`.

Comment: Are you precluded from just using an IDE? I'm more familiar with command and terminal stuff on the UNIX side. Sorry I couldn't be more help.